# Query to include only particular employees from table per_periods_of_service that are not terminated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the below query -

```
select assignment_number,
effective_start_Date,
grade_id,
job_id,
object_version_number
from per_all_assignments_m
```

I want to include only those employees in the above query that have `termination_date not null` 
in table peR_periods_of_service. the common column in both tables is periodS_of_service_id and period_id How to achieve this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results please.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing can be done using `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from peR_periods_of_service pos
              where pos.period_id = per_all_assignments_m.periodS_of_service_id and
                    pos.termination_date is not null
             )
```